# Xcode 7.1 Error: "The file 'project_name' couldn't be opened because you don't have permission to view it" using Parse and FB SDK

Tags: parse-platform, xcode7, facebook-sdk-4.0

After linking all the frameworks of Facebook and Parse, and solving all the problems(using Xcode 7.1, and Facebook SDK 4). I got new one when I try to run it:

> The file 'project_name' couldn't be opened because you don't have permission to view it